# R explicit subscript function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for an explicit function to subscript elements in R, say `subscript(x,i)` to mean `x[i]`.

The reason that I need this traces back to a piece of code using `dplyr` and `magrittr` pipe operator, which is not a pipe, and where I need to divide by the first element of each column.

```
pipedDF <- rawdata %>% filter, merge, summarize, dcast %>%
   mutate_each( funs(./subscript(., 1) ), -index)
```

I think this would do the trick and keep that pipe syntax which people like.

Without `dplyr` it would look like this...

Example,

```
> df
  index    a   b c
1     1 6.00 5.0 4
2     2 7.50 6.0 5
3     3 5.00 4.5 6
4     4 9.00 7.0 7

> data.frame(sapply(df, function(x)x/x[1]))
  index    a   b    c
1     1 1.00 1.0 1.00
2     2 1.25 1.2 1.25
3     3 0.83 0.9 1.50
4     4 1.50 1.4 1.75
```

> 

Comment: Does `.[1]` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `'['`, as in

```
x<-5:1
'['(x,2)
# [1] 4
```

Comment: there's also `head(x, 1)`, for OP's particular case